# Problems with Model binding and validation attributes with asp.net Web API

Tags: validation, asp.net-web-api, model-binding

I am writing a Web API with ASP.NET Web API, and make use of the following View Model.
I seem to be having a problem with the data binding when there are two validation attributes on a particular property (i.e. [Required] and [StringLength(10)]).

When posting a JSON value from a client to a controller action of the form:

// POST api/list

public void Post([FromBody] TaskViewModel taskVM)

I observe the following:

- If I remove one of the multiple attributes everything is bound OK;
- If I leave in the multiple attributes, the client recieves a 500 internal server error   and the body of the Post method is never reached.

Any ideas why this happens?
Cheers

```
public class TaskViewModel
{

    //Default Constructor
    public TaskViewModel() { }


    public static TaskViewModel MakeTaskViewModel(Task task) 
    {
        return new TaskViewModel(task);
    }

    //Constructor
    private TaskViewModel(Task task)
    {
        this.TaskId = task.TaskID;
        this.Description = task.Description;
        this.StartDate = task.StartDate;
        this.Status = task.Status;
        this.ListID = task.ListID;
    }

    public Guid TaskId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public System.DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Status { get; set; }        

    public System.Guid ListID { get; set; }       
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to inspect what is inside in the 500 internal server

- make sure that you turn [customerror](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) off in your web.config
- If you selfhost web.API you need to set `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;`
- use your browser development console's network tab (in IE, Chrome you can get the console with F12) or if you are using FireFox then use FireBug or a thrid party tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

Then you can see what went wrong on the server and go further to solve your problem.

In your case this is in the response:

> "Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Property
>   'StartDate' on type 'MvcApplication3.Controllers.TaskViewModel' is
>   invalid. **Value-typed properties marked as [Required] must also be
>   marked with [DataMember(IsRequired=true)] to be recognized as
>   required**. Consider attributing the declaring type with [DataContract]
>   and the property with
>   [DataMember(IsRequired=true)].","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"

So your problem is not that you have two attributes but that you've marked your properties with `[Required]` to solve this the exception tells you what to do.

You need to add `[DataMember(IsRequired=true)]` to your required properties where the property type is a value type (e.g int, datatime, etc.):

So change your `TaskViewModel` to:

```cs
[DataContract]
public class TaskViewModel
{

    //Default Constructor
    public TaskViewModel() { }

    [DataMember]
    public Guid TaskId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataMember]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public System.DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataMember]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public System.Guid ListID { get; set; }
}
```

Some side notes:

- You need to reference the System.Runtime.Serialization dll in order to use the `DataMemberAttribute`
- You need to mark your class with `[DataContract]` and you need to mark all of its properties with `[DataMember]` not just the required ones.

Comment: Great, that's fixed problem. Much Appreciated.