# Action doesn't get called in Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, model-binding

I am having some issues with ASP.Net MVC 4 - Web API.

I have the following action in my API Controller:

```
public void Post([FromBody] Integration integration)
{
    _repository.Add(integration);
}
```

For some reason, my breakpoint on `_repository.Add(integration);` never comes through.

Here is what I am posting using the `WebClient`

```
POST https://ef52667f-3a6e-4a58-b548-e82b72186b5f.o365apps.net/api/integration HTTP/1.1
AccessToken: Vk1Ga4/L/BHYGNY1wVoq3tgGmVlu0YfPukZTlNqnFEK0HH
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: ef52667f-3a6e-4a58-b548-e82b72186b5f.o365apps.net
Content-Length: 334
Expect: 100-continue

IntegrationId=c7456461-9e99-4e82-85d5-072670d270b5&Key=2999A604-30C9-423B-8500-8706673EEAFF&ApiUrl=https%3a%2f%2fapi.site.com%2fintegration.asmx&Web=https%3a%2f%2fsiteapp.sharepoint.com%2f&RemoteWeb=https%3a%2f%2ftesting.site.com%2fintegration%2f&ListName=Issues&IncomingAllowed=True&OutgoingAllowed=True&DeletionAllowed=True
```

Here is the response I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 36
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Set-Cookie: ARRAffinity=5d9ceead697ee36c96ed0c04e0e51d80b3f1f3f7fced5c04c89cc370205e464d;Path=/;Domain=ef52667f-3a6e-4a58-b548-e82b72186b5f.o365apps.net
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By: ARR/2.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Set-Cookie: WAWebSiteSID=3317c656d3214c81a19cbff73bb5d6cf; Path=/; HttpOnly
Date: Wed, 20 Mar 2013 20:02:44 GMT

{"Message":"An error has occurred."}
```

Interestingly, I have another similar method which works perfectly fine:

```
public AuthResponse Post([FromBody] AuthRequest authRequest)
{
    var authResponse = new AuthResponse();

    try
    {
        . . .  
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        authResponse.Success = false;
        authResponse.Message = e.Message;
    }

    return authResponse;
}
```

Am I missing something here?

FYI, here my `Integration` model:

```
[SharePointList("Integrations")]
public class Integration : Entity
{
    public Integration(int id) : base(id) { }

    public Integration() { }

    [Required]
    public string ApiUrl { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool DeletionAllowed { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool IncomingAllowed { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    [Required]
    public Guid IntegrationId { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    [Required]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ListName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool OutgoingAllowed { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string RemoteWeb { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Web { get; set; }

    public override object this[string property]
    {
        get { return GetType().GetProperty(property).GetValue(this, null); }
        set
        {
            if (property.Equals("Id")) throw new Exception("Cannot set Id through an indexer.");

            if (property.Equals("IntegrationId"))
            {
                IntegrationId = new Guid((string) value);
                return;
            }

            if (property.Equals("Title"))
            {
                Key = value as string;
                return;
            }

            PropertyInfo propertyInfo = GetType().GetProperty(property);
            if (propertyInfo == null) throw new Exception(property + " is not a valid property.");

            propertyInfo.SetValue(this, value, null);
        }
    }
}
```

**Entity.cs**

```
public abstract class Entity : IEntity
{
    protected Entity(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }

    protected Entity() { }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public abstract object this[string property] { get; set; }
}
```

**IEntity.cs**

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int Id { get; }

    object this[string property] { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you include exception details in errors and share the error response with the stacktrace. You can change the setting using this [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.httpconfiguration.includeerrordetailpolicy(v=vs.108).aspx).

Comment: I'm quite sure that you have the same problem what was mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14499244/problems-with-model-binding-and-validation-attributes-with-asp-net-web-api?lq=1

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

The solution that involves placing DataContract/DataMember attributes on top of your classes/properties is not proper solution of the issue.

What you need to do to get rid of WCF remnants is:

Add this to your global.asax:

```
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.RemoveAll(typeof(ModelValidatorProvider), v => v is InvalidModelValidatorProvider);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.RequiredMemberSelect‌or = new SuppressRequiredMemberSelector();
```

Create SupressRequiredMemberSelector class:

```
public class SuppressRequiredMemberSelector : IRequiredMemberSelector
{
    public bool IsRequiredMember(MemberInfo member)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This will solve your issue without need to change annotations and is widely accepted "bug fix" for Web API as it uses extensibility it offers, nothing else.

Comment: You are only changing JsonFormatter will your solution work with using XML? You have mentioned that this is "widely accepted "bug fix"" can you add some references in your post?

Comment: You can search around, but this was the primary site where issue was reported afaik: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/270